# How do access Redux state in react-router ProtectedRoute?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I want to restrict the access of certain routes depending on whether or not the user is logged in.

Currently, I have:

**index.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ProtectedRoute from './ProtectedRoute';
import configureStore, { history } from './configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={MyContainer1} />
                <ProtectedRoute exact path="/user" component={MyContainer2} />
                <Route exact path="/login" component={MyContainer3} />
                <ProtectedRoute exact path="/setup" component={MyContainer4} />
            </Switch>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

**ProtectedRoute.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: any) => {
    const isLoggedIn = true; // How do I get the Redux state here?
    
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) =>
                isLoggedIn ? (
                    <Component {...props} />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: '/login',
                            state: { from: props.location },
                        }}
                    />
                )
            }
        />
    );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

I also have a Redux global store of reducers here:

**reducer.ts**

```
const createRootReducer = (history: History<any>) =>
    combineReducers({
        router: connectRouter(history),
        login: LoginReducer,
        setup: SetupReducer,
    });

export default createRootReducer;
```

In my `LoginReducer`, I have a flag that keeps track of whether or not the user is logged in. Now, how do I access that flag in my `ProtectedRoute.tsx` code?  When working with normal components, I would create a Container with `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` and access the Redux state that way. I'm not sure if it's possible or equivalent to do it in a functional component that is `ProtectedRoute`.

Comment: You can use `const isLoggedIn  = useSelector(state => state.login.isLoggedIn)` in your `ProtectedRoute` component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `useSelector` in your `ProtectedRoute` functional component to access the redux store.

Like this -

```
const isLoggedIn = useSelector(state => state.login.isLoggedIn)
```

Here is a sample codesandbox on how `useSelector` can be used in your application - https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-useselector-usedispatch-sample-8l0sv?file=/src/Counter.js:504-512